# how to put the last block in place of the first one in a media query

Tags: html, css

I have an example of a simple grid in which when the screen size is less than 767 pixels, all blocks stretch to fill the screen.
Section 2 moves to the very bottom when this size (767 pixels) is reached. And I have something like this: Section 1, footer, section 2. Is it possible to somehow make section 2 at the very top? (section 2, section 1, footer)

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  

.wrapper {
    max-width: 1200px; 
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 0px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.leftcolumn {
    float: left;
    width: 65%;
}

.rightcolumn {
    float: left;
    width: 35%;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.footer {
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    background: rgba(221, 221, 221, 0.3);
    margin-top: 20px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .leftcolumn, .rightcolumn {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0;
    }
}
```

```
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="leftcolumn">
                1 section
                <div class="footer">
                   footer
                </div>
            </div>
        
            <div class="rightcolumn">
              2 section
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is what I have now:
[image]

Here is what I want to get:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did these changes in your code:

Use `grid` instead `float`. Then set `grid-column` and `grid-row` for grid items. Then change these for screen size smaller than 768px.

**Note** also I changed your HTML for this purpose:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 1200px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 0px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 65% 35%;
}

.rightcolumn {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.footer {
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(221, 221, 221, 0.3);
  margin-top: 20px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .row {
    grid-template-columns: 100%;
  }
  .rightcolumn {
    grid-row: 1 / 2;
    grid-column: 1 / 2;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  .footer{
    grid-row: 3 / 4;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="leftcolumn">
      1 section
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      footer
    </div>
    <div class="rightcolumn">
      2 section
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> You can simply do it by using flexbox and a little bit of change in your **html** code.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 1200px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  padding: 0 0px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.left {
  width: 65%;
}

.rightcolumn {
  width: 35%;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.footer {
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(221, 221, 221, 0.3);
  margin-top: 20px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .row {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .left,
  .rightcolumn {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .left {
    order: 2;
  }
  .rightcolumn {
    order: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="left">
      <div class="leftcolumn">
        1 section
      </div>
      <div class="footer">
        footer
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rightcolumn">
      2 section
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> You can set the width of .footer div according to your preference above 767 pixels, I have set it 100%;